# use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to Objective-C coding ,please bear with me to ask if this is simple question
My Header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*) response;

@end
```

My Implementation file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSMutableData *receivedData  =[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.                  
    receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        // Release the receivedData object.
        receivedData = nil;
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
     }
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData =[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];


    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse object.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
@end
```

when i run the code at implementation `appDelegate`  it gives warning

> Method definition for connection:didRecieveResponse :not found

and where

> -(void)connection line it gives  "use of undelcared identifier connection did u mean Collection".

Comment: `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification;` is not required in `.h` file. But don't know about the error you receiving

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare the method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*) response;
```

in your header file if you are using the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` Protocol in your code. Just add the protocol in the implementation and use the methods from that protocol.